# Computer the flux of $\nabla \ln \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ across an icosahedron centered at the origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Let $S$ be the surface of an icosahedron centered at origin) and let $$f(x,y,z)=\ln \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} .$$ Calculate the flux $$\iint_S (\nabla f \cdot n) d\sigma,$$ where $n$ is the outward unit normal vector on $S$.

[My attempt]

I tried to use divergence theorem.  $$\iint (\nabla f \cdot n) d\sigma = \iiint (\nabla \cdot \nabla f ) dV ,$$ where $(\nabla \cdot \nabla f ) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2+z^2}$. However, I can't find a parametrization of the icosahedron to find the triple integral. How to find this value?

Comment: Does the Divergence Theorem apply?

Comment: Yes, i did but i can solve this problem yet.

Comment: Review the hypotheses.

Comment: is there problem in hypotheses? could you explain in detail? I cant understand..

Comment: The vector field needs to be $C^1$ everywhere inside the surface ... There is an obvious singularity here at the origin.

Comment: I suspect this problem may not be written as intended, since there doesn't seem to be a better way than just parameterizing a face $F$ of the icosahedron $I$ and using symmetry to compute $$\iint_I \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma = 20 \iint_F \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma .$$ On the other hand, if $f := (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1 / 2}$, there is a much cleaner method for computing the integral. (In 2 dimensions the radial function with this property is $\log \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.)

Comment: That's really good point i missed, Thank you! Then, this problem need to calculate surface integral directly, but i can't still know how to solve this.

Comment: wow, if we can show that this intergral is independent to rigid motion, that symmetry property is really true. is this independence alway true for surface integral?

Comment: The fact that we can reduce the integral to one over a single face is a consequence of the fact that the integrand is a radial function, so it is preserved under arbitrary rotations, including the symmetries of the icosahedron.

Comment: @Travis: The vector field is radial, but the flux integrand is not.

Comment: You can use the fact that, after a rotation of the icosahedron (which again doesn't affect the value of the integral) the vertices of the icosahedron are the points $a \cdot (0, \pm 1, \pm \phi)$ together with their cyclic permutations.

Comment: You're right, by "integrand" I meant just the vector field $\nabla f$, not all of $(\nabla f) \cdot {\bf n}$−−−but that wording was at best imprecise and at worst misleading. hew, to be clear my comment about symmetry still holds, since $(\nabla f) \cdot {\bf n}$ is preserved by isometries of the icosahedron.

Comment: After playing with this problem some, I found the flux to be $$60 \rho \int _0^{\pi / 3} \log \left( \frac{1}{4} \lambda^2  \sec^2 \theta +1\right) \, d\theta ,$$ where $\rho$ is the radius of the inscribed sphere and $\lambda := 3 - \sqrt{5}$ is the ratio of the distance between the center of a triangular face and a vertex and $\rho$---but I don't see how to express this nicely in closed form.

Comment: The coefficient of $\rho$ in the expression for the flux is $13.35031\!\ldots$. Since $\nabla f$ is radial and has positive divergence, the flux across the icosahedron should be between that the fluxes across the inscribed and circumscribed spheres, the flux should be between $4 \pi \rho$ and $4 \pi \sqrt{1 + \lambda^2} \rho$, and evaluating the coefficients numerically shows this to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, I suspect that this question might have been prepared incorrectly: I don't see a method better than exploiting symmetry and integrating directly, and the resulting integral doesn't appear to have a closed form in terms of elementary functions, though it does have an unpleasant expression in terms of dilogarithms.

Since the integrand $\nabla f \cdot {\bf n}$ is invariant under symmetries of the icosahedron $S$, we need only integrate over a suitable triangle $T$ contained in a face $F$:
$$\iint_S \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma = 20 \iint_F \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma = 120 \iint_T \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma .$$

[image]

Now, using the fact that the central angle between two adjacent vertices of $S$ is $\arccos \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ gives that the distance between the center $U$ of $F$ and a corner of $F$ is $\lambda R$, where $R$ is the radius of the sphere inscribed in $S$, and $\lambda := 3 - \sqrt{5} \approx 0.76393\!\ldots$.

In spherical coordinates centered at the center of $S$, $\nabla f = \rho^{-1} {\bf \hat \rho}$, so at a point $x$ on $F$ at a distance $r$ from $U$, $$(\nabla f)(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2 + r^2}} \hat\rho ,$$ and then some straightforward trigonometery shows that $$\nabla f \cdot {\bf n} = \frac{R}{R^2 + r^2} .$$
Thus, in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ on $F$ centered at $U$, we have
$$\iint_E \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2} R \lambda \sec \theta} \underbrace{\frac{R}{R^2 + r^2}}_{\nabla f \cdot {\bf n}} \underbrace{r \,dr \,d\theta}_{d\sigma}.$$
Computing the inner integral gives
$$\frac{1}{2} R \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \log\left(\frac{1}{4} \lambda^2 \sec^2 \theta + 1\right) \,d\theta .$$
This integral, however, does not appear to have a closed form in terms of elementary functions. It does have an explicit formula in terms of dilogarithms, but it's too complicated to be worth reproducing here. I would anyway be pleased to see a more tractable expression for this quantity.

*Edit* I made some progress on this integral---replacing $\frac{1}{2} \lambda$ with $\alpha$ and applying Feynman's trick we can reduce computing this integral to understanding $\frac{\arctan \beta \,d\beta}{\beta^2 - 3}$. Maple gives a slightly nicer expression, but it still involves dilogarithms. I didn't push the (rather ugly) computation to its end, but the form of the expression suggests that the integral can be written in terms of elementary functions and three instances of [Legendre's chi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function). It's not clear whether one can improve on this.

At any rate, the flux of $\nabla f$ across $S$ is thus
$$\iint_S \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma = 60 \left[\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \log\left(\frac{1}{4} \lambda^2 \sec^2 \theta + 1\right) \,d\theta\right] R .$$ Integrating numerically gives that the quantity in brackets (just as well, the flux across the icosahedron with $R = 1$) is $13.35031\!\ldots$.

Since $\nabla \cdot \nabla f > 0$ everywhere, the Divergence Theorem gives that the flux across $S$ is between the fluxes of the spheres inscribing and circumscribing $S$, giving the cheap bounds
$$4 \pi R < \iint_S \nabla f \cdot {\bf n} \,d\sigma < 4 \pi \sqrt{R^2 + \lambda^2} .$$

*Remark* Another reason to suspect that the question is not what the preparer intended is that the analogous problem in dimension $2$---computing the flux of the vector field $\nabla \log\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ across a regular polygon in $\Bbb R^2$ with the origin on its interior---*does* admit an efficient solution that uses the Divergence Theorem and the fact that $\nabla \cdot \nabla \log\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0$. A vector field in $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$ with this behavior is $g(x, y, z) = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{-1 / 2}$.